# How to implement Material Design Choreographing surface animations

Tags: android, animation, material-design

I wonder how to implement the Choreographing surface animations (like https://material.google.com/motion/choreography.html#choreography-creation in Choreographic surface section).

I actually used both Alpha animation and Translate animation but it seems like it is not exactly what we can see on the material design site.

Did someone have a good example of how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with various combination of scale, alpha and pivot.

Can you look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47059566/1042124)

The Choreography given in the documentation can be achieved by different combination of scale, alpha and pivot.

Let me know if you need any further assistance.